# How to use async alternative for Promise.resolve().then()?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Run the snippets and look at their durations you'll see that first snippet executes `log('Synchronous 2')` before `billion loops done`. It spent 0ms, but 2nd snippet using async keyword blocks `log('Synchronous 2')`until the loop is finished.

```js
const tick = Date.now();
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}ms`);

const notBlocked = () => {
    return Promise.resolve().then(() =>  {
        let i = 0;
        while(i < 1000000000) { i++; } //runs asynchronically
        return ' billion loops done';
    })
}

log(' Synchronous 1');
notBlocked().then(log);
log(' Synchronous 2');
```

The log('Synchronous 2') is blocked

```js
const tick = Date.now();
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}ms`);

const notBlocked = async() => {
    let i = 0;
    while(i < 100000000) { i++; } //runs synchronically and blocks main thread
    return ' billion loops done';
}

log(' Synchronous 1');
notBlocked().then(log);
log(' Synchronous 2');
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. What is the outcome you expected, and why?

Comment: What behavior are you trying to achieve? Your log calls are sync and thus happen before the promise resolution. Do you want to wait until notBlocked finishes executing before continuing?

Comment: Run the code above and you'll see log 2 runs before notBlocked function returns result. But I want to use async await fashion to write notBlocked() and I couldn't.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I want to figure out what are the limitations of async await. When I should use one over the other.

Comment: @user2734550 When it's a general topic that can be learnt from online documentation you should post on SO with care. I think you can improve your question though. Change the "I couldn't figure out..." part to a more formal question about async/await, explaining why the code you included is not good for you. The question should be clear and useful to other users that met your same problem.

Comment: @user2734550 - you can't use `await` without `async`, that's the syntax sugar for `Promise` -> `then` pair (to simplify). It is unclear what you want to acheive as the snippet runs as expected: first `log` is sync, runs first, `notBlocked` is async, gets queued, second `log` is sync, runs second. What's the problem? You need to read up on how [event loop works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Async functions run synchronously until they hit an await, so if your goal is to use an async function to delay some code as a microtask, you'll need to stick an await in there, even if it's awaiting something useless.

```js
const tick = Date.now();
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}ms`);

const notBlocked = async () => {
  await undefined; // yield until the microtasks run
  let i = 0;
  while(i < 1000000000) { i++; }
  return ' billion loops done';
}

log(' Synchronous 1');
notBlocked().then(log);
log(' Synchronous 2');
```

Comment: I guess I didn't completely understand async await. This is such a weird solution to me but it does work...

Comment: Oh yeah, definitely weird. I would never write code like this for production.

Comment: It seems like this is a limitation of async await.

Comment: Now I think of it. it's no different than Promise.resolve().then() except most devs won't understand what's going on here, right? So I guess it's not really a limitation of async await

Answer (score 1):

To run the function in another worker I would use the `setTimeout` function. I created the util function `detach` for this purpose:

```js
const tick = Date.now();
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}ms`);

// Run a function in another worker.
const detach = (fn) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            fn();
            resolve();
        }, 0);
    });
}

const runLoop = () => {
    let i = 0;
    while(i < 1000000000) { i++; }
    return ' billion loops done';
}

const notBlocked = async () => {
    await detach(runLoop);
}

// Enable the use of async/await (assuming your in a module and not in an async function)
(async () => {
    log(' Synchronous 1');
    const promiseNotBlocking = notBlocked(); // Get the promise
    log(' Synchronous 2');
    await promiseNotBlocking;
})()
```

Comment: log2 is still blocked for 500ms.

Comment: I updated my answer